# Labeling images for TrainImageContentDetector

Tags: image, machine-learning, annotation

I want to use `TrainImageContentDetector` on a directory of ~2k unlabeled images. I'm willing to put in the effort to label them, but I was never good at using "Drawing Tools" or the "Image Ribbon".

Can anyone suggest an *ergonomic workflow to draw the rectangles/masks* over the image to specify different objects, in a way that is simple and scales?

Perhaps there's an internal tool that developers used to make the examples by hand:

[image]

Here's an example image and a very bad attempt at a workflow to get started:

```
img = CloudGet @ "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/f82a9e7e-81b7-419d-84e4-73de383f8d62";
Canvas @ Graphics @ img
(* add rectangles and shift enter *)
polys = DeleteDuplicates /@ 
   Cases[%, _BezierCurve | _BezierCurveBox, \[Infinity]][[All, 1]];
Graphics[{img, EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[None], Polygon /@ polys}]
```

[image]

---

**Update**

Here is a modification of @Batracos's answer that addresses point #1 and half of point #4. I'm still unsure how to make the rectangles editable and the carousel interactive. The most crucial missing piece is how to undo/edit or simply delete individual boxes, because it's very easy to get them wrong!

[image]

```
pointsToRec[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}] := Rectangle[{Min[x1, x2], Min[y1, y2]}, {Max[x1, x2], Max[y1, y2]}]
clipCoords[{x_,y_},{w_,h_}]:={Clip[x,{0,w}],Clip[y,{0,h}]}
scaleBox[{w_,h_}][Rectangle[{x1_,y1_},{x2_,y2_}]]:=Rectangle[{x1 w,y1 h},{x2 w,y2 h}]
scaleBox[{w_,h_}][list:{__Rectangle}]:=scaleBox[{w,h}]/@list

ClearAll[boxCreator];
boxCreator[classList_, ifns_, labels_:<||>] := 
Panel @ DynamicModule[
    {
        (* additional stuff *)
        idx = 1, i, allboxes=labels, box={}, class = classList[[1]], nav, classColors = AssociationThread[classList->ResourceFunction["SampleColors"][Length@classList]], 
        thumbs, carousel, len, ithumb, window=Min[8, Length@ifns], cf, 
        (* states *)
        first = True, mouseDown = False, left = {0,0}, current = {0,0}, draggingQ = False, pos = None,
        (* settings*)
        clipQ = True, scaledQ = True, guidesQ = True,
        (* variables *)
        dims, color, margin = 5, size = 400, sizeC, locator
    },
    
    color = classColors[class];
    i = Import@ifns[[idx]];
    len = Length@ifns;
    box = Lookup[allboxes, ifns[[idx]], {}];
    
    dims = ImageDimensions[i];
    size = 500;
    sizeC = N @ Log[10, size];
    color = If[ImageMeasurements[i, "MeanIntensity"] < .4, White, Black];
    locator = Graphics @ {
                {
                    Opacity[Dynamic[.4 Boole[MousePosition["Graphics"] =!= None]]], ColorNegate[color],
                    AbsoluteThickness[3], Circle[{0,0}, 10{1,1}], 
                    Line[{{{-15, 0}, {-5, 0}}, {{5, 0}, {15, 0}}, {{0, -15}, {0, -5}}, {{0, 5}, {0, 15}}}]
                },
                Opacity[Dynamic[Boole[MousePosition["Graphics"] =!= None]]], color,
                Circle[{0,0}, 10{1,1}],
                Line[{{{-15, 0}, {-5, 0}}, {{5, 0}, {15, 0}}, {{0, -15}, {0, -5}}, {{0, 5}, {0, 15}}}]
            };
    
    (* additional functions *)
                              (*save state*)         (*move*)                    (*load boxes*)                          (*load image*)
    nav[n_Integer] := (allboxes[ifns[[idx]]]=box; idx=Clip[n, {1,Length[ifns]}]; box=Lookup[allboxes, ifns[[idx]], {}]; i=Import[ifns[[idx]]]);
    
    ithumb[fn_] := ithumb[fn] = ImageResize[Import[fn], {230,140}, Padding->Black (*, ConformationMethod->"Fit"... how to maintain aspect ?*)];
    carousel[idx_, slots_:window] := Module[{cs, ce},
        cs = If[idx < slots, 1, Min[len-slots+1, idx-slots+1]]; ce = If[idx < slots, slots, idx];
        Grid[{MapAt[Framed[#,FrameStyle->{Blend[{Yellow,Orange}],Thickness[2]}, FrameMargins->{0,0}]&, ithumb /@ Part[ifns, cs;;ce], Min[idx, window]]},
         Spacings->{1,0}, ItemSize->All, Background->Gray]
    ];
    cf = If[#==={}, #, {FaceForm[Opacity[.2], Lookup[classColors, #[[2]], color]], EdgeForm[Lookup[classColors, #[[2]], color]], #[[1]]}] &;
    
    Deploy @ Column[{
    Framed[#, FrameMargins->0, FrameStyle->LightGray]& @ 
    EventHandler[
        MouseAppearance[Graphics[{
            (* image *)
            Inset[Dynamic@i, Center, Center, Scaled[1]],
            FaceForm[Opacity[.2, color]], EdgeForm[color],
            (* boxes present in list *)
            Dynamic[cf /@ box],
            (* box being currently drawn *)
            {
                Opacity[Dynamic[Boole[!first]]], EdgeForm[Opacity[Dynamic[Boole[!first]]]],
                FaceForm[], Rectangle[Dynamic@left, Dynamic@current]
            },
            (* guide lines *)
            {Opacity[Dynamic[.5 Boole[guidesQ && first && MousePosition["Graphics"] =!= None]], color], InfiniteLine[Dynamic@current, {1,0}], InfiniteLine[Dynamic@current, {0,1}]},
            (* locator *)
            Inset[locator, Dynamic[current], Center, Offset[{25, 25}]]
        },
            ImageSize -> Dynamic[size], 
            PlotRange -> Dynamic@If[scaledQ, {{0,1}, {0,1}}, Tuples[{{0}, dims}]],
            AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio[i],
            Background -> GrayLevel[.1],
            ImageMargins -> margin
        ], Graphics[]],
        {
        {"MouseDown", 1} :> (If[first,
            (* record first box corner *)
            left = current;
            first = False,
            (* record second box corner and save box *)
            If[
                EuclideanDistance[left, current] > If[scaledQ, .005, 2],
                AppendTo[box, pointsToRec[left, current] -> class];
                first = True
            ]
        ]),
        {"MouseUp", 1} :> (
            If[!first && draggingQ,
                (* record second box corner and save box *)
                If[
                    EuclideanDistance[left, current] > If[scaledQ, .005, 2],
                    AppendTo[box, pointsToRec[left, current] -> class];
                    first = True
                ]
            ];
            draggingQ = False
        ),
        {"MouseClicked", 2} :> (If[!first,
            (* cancel current selection *)
            first = True; draggingQ = False,
            (* cancel last selection *)
            If[Length[box] > 0, box = Most[box]]; draggingQ = False
        ]),
        "MouseMoved" :> (
            (* store current mouse position *)
            pos = MousePosition["Graphics"];
            If[VectorQ[pos], current = If[clipQ, clipCoords[pos, If[scaledQ, {1, 1}, dims]], pos]];
        ),
        "MouseDragged" :> (
            draggingQ = True;
        ),
        "RightArrowKeyDown" :> (   (*doesn't work*)
           nav[idx+1];
        ),
        "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> ((*doesn't work, idk why*)
            nav[idx-1];
        )
        }
    ],
    Row[{
        Framed[Pane[Dynamic @ carousel[idx], Dynamic @ size, ImageSizeAction->"ShrinkToFit"], Background->Gray, FrameMargins->None], "\n",
        
        (*"Index: " Slider[Dynamic[idx, {nav[idx]&, Automatic, nav[#1]&}], {1, Length[ifns], 1}], Dynamic[idx], "\n\n", *) (*doesn't work, idk why*)
        RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[class], classList], "\n",
        Button["Prev", nav[idx-1]],
        Button["Next", nav[idx+1]], "\t", 
        Button["Save", allboxes[ifns[[idx]]]=box; Print[Iconize[allboxes, "Labels"]]],"\n\n",
        
        
        "Clip", Checkbox[Dynamic[clipQ]],
        "Scale", Checkbox[Dynamic[scaledQ, 
            (scaledQ = #; If[# && Length[box] > 0, box[[All,1]] = scaleBox[1/dims][box[[All,1]]], box[[All,1]] = scaleBox[dims][box[[All,1]]]])&]],
        "Guides", Checkbox[Dynamic[guidesQ]],
        Button["Clear", box = {}; first = True; draggingQ = False], "\n",
        "Scale: ", Slider[Dynamic[sizeC, (sizeC = #; size = 10^#)&], {2.5, 3.1}], Dynamic[sizeC], "\n\n" (*shouldn't delimiters work in rows/cols?*)
        
        }]
    }]
]
```

Then to test it:

```
dir=CreateDirectory[]
Do[Export[dir<>"/"<>ToString[i]<>".jpeg",ResourceFunction["RandomPhoto"][500,300]],{i,15}];

classes={"face", "tree", "road"};
fns=FileNames["*.jpeg",dir];
previousWork=<||> (*replace with iconized after clicking save*);

boxCreator[classes, fns, previousWork]
```

Comment: This should be built in to the system, and image masks have never been easy enough

Comment: Yes thanks. There are many front end gui building experts here, please try your hand at this!

Comment: @Batracos changing the box type in the radio button bar makes my mouse disappear, do you see that too?

Comment: Thanks @user5601 this is pretty good but needs the ability to edit labels individually, also the frame rate is too slow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Updated answer^2

(the old answer is below)

I have updated the code to manage image selection, class selection and editing. The main annoyance is that event handler needs some box structure to be selected to work and the only way I manage to do it is by keeping the curson in the input field. Such is life ¯_(ツ)_/¯

[Animation in WebM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYeOI.jpg)

#### Helpers

Some small updates to the class input field to make it less aggressive in selecting the first proposal

```
Clear[suggestionField]
suggestionField[Dynamic[x_, f_:Null], Dynamic[list_] | list_, hint_ : ""] := 
    InputField[
        Dynamic[x, (x = #; f[x])&],
        String,
        FieldHint -> hint,
        FieldCompletionFunction :> getSuggestions[list],
        ContinuousAction -> True
    ]
```

This code can be use to select up to 10 suggestion from a list sorted by `EditDistance` and with a simple fuzzy matching (not a cool as the one in sublime text but that is more complex to implement here)

```
getSuggestions[list_][string_?StringQ] :=
    list // 
        DeleteDuplicates //
        Select[StringLength[#] > 0 &] // 
        Select[StringContainsQ[RegularExpression[StringRiffle[Characters[string], ".*"]], IgnoreCase -> True]] // 
        SortBy[Function[x, EditDistance[x, string]]] //
        Take[#, UpTo[10]]&
getSuggestions[list_][_] := {}
```

A separate deginition for the locator, because I just don't like the system one. (Probably more code could be factored out)

```
Clear[locator]
locator[Dynamic[color_] | color_, opts___?OptionQ] := 
    Graphics[{
        {
            Opacity[.4], ColorNegate[color],
            AbsoluteThickness[3], Circle[{0,0}, 10{1,1}], 
            Line[{{{-15, 0}, {-5, 0}}, {{5, 0}, {15, 0}}, {{0, -15}, {0, -5}}, {{0, 5}, {0, 15}}}]
        },
        color,
        Circle[{0,0}, 10{1,1}],
        Line[{{{-15, 0}, {-5, 0}}, {{5, 0}, {15, 0}}, {{0, -15}, {0, -5}}, {{0, 5}, {0, 15}}}],
    },
        opts, ImageSize -> {25, 25}
    ]
```

Some formatting for the bounding boxes to take a little less space. Used in the new box list.

```
formatBox[Rectangle[{x1_,x2_},{x3_,x4_}]] := Sequence[Round[x1],Round[x2],"|", Round[x3],Round[x4],"\[Rule]"]
```

A utility to get a fixed window around a point. Used in the carousel

```
slidingWindow[i_, max_, size_] := Take[
    DeleteCases[0] @ DeleteDuplicates @ Flatten @ Thread[{
        PadRight[Range[i, Max[1,i - size], -1],    size, 0],
        PadRight[Range[i, Min[max, i + size], +1], size, 0]
    }], UpTo[size]] // Sort
```

This is to generate a consistent (and hopefully decent) color given a label

```
exprColor[expr_] :=
    Lighter[ColorData["BalancedHue", Mod[Hash[Unevaluated[expr]], 360]/360], .2]
```

A helper to load in-core and out-of-core images

```
Clear[getImage]
getImage[list_List, size_ : Automatic] := Map[getImage[#, size]&, list]
getImage[file_String?FileExistsQ, size_ : Automatic] := getImage[fastImageImport[file], size] (* fixed this line *)
getImage[image_Image?ImageQ, size_: Automatic] := ImageResize[Image[image, ImageSize -> 500, ImageResolution -> 72], Replace[size, Automatic -> Scaled[1]]]
getImage[e_, _] := Graphics[Text[Row[{"Failed to load image: ", e}]], ImageSize -> 500, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

Some internal function to skip the `Import` framework on common filenames

```
fastImageImport[file_String] := Module[
    {ext, imported},
    ext = FileExtension[file];
    Switch[ext,
        "jpg" | "jpeg",
            imported = First @ Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadJPEG[file],
        "png",
            imported = First @ Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG[file];
            Image`ImportExportDump`DeleteCachePNG[],
        "tif" | "tiff",
            imported = First @ Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTIFF[file]
    ];

    (* If not an image yet, try Import *)
    If[!ImageQ[imported], imported = Import[file]];
    If[!ImageQ[imported], Throw[$Failed]];
    imported
]
fastImageImport[File[string_]] := fastImageImport[string]
```

#### Code

Now the gory part. <s>It's still not out-of-core but that is a small adaptation (I might edit again if I have time).</s>

The main changes are

- out-of-core support
- the support for a list of images (and annotations)
- thumbnail carousel
- arrow movement
- the edit button which enables

  - box selection by clicking
  - box resizing and moving using locators

The latter is implemented via an parallel GraphicsBox with locator to move the box center and adjust the corners. The box `id` can be picked from the list of current boxes that are drown on the side. While in edit mode, writing in the class field with edit the class name for the current box.

I have also tweak the code to make more use of MousePosition because setting it via EventHandler was sending a lot of unnecessary traffic between the kernel and the frontend.

That said, is it probably still full of bugs so bear with me... =)

```
ClearAll[boxCreatorList]
SetAttributes[boxCreatorList, HoldAll]
boxCreatorList[imageList_, previousResults_ : Automatic] := 
DynamicModule[
    {
        max, classes,
        (* to keep only one serialized copy of the input data *)
        images = imageList,
        data = previousResults,
        (* states *)
        image, class, dims, range, color,
        id = 1, (*box id*)
        i = 1, (* image id*)
        j = 1, (* class id*)
        thumbID = 1, (* image thumbnail id*)
        first = True, mouseDown = False, left = {0,0}, current = {0,0},
        mouse = Dynamic@MousePosition[{"Graphics", PaneSelector}, {-5, -5}],
        (* settings*)
        clipQ = True, guidesQ = True, draggingQ = False, editQ = False, editClassQ = False,
        (* variables *)
        margin = 20, size, sizeC, minMove = 2, boxcenter, boxsize, thumbnail,
        (* herlpers *)
        safePos, getClasses, loadImage, addBox, deleteBox, editBox, checkCoord, carousel, styled
    },
    
    (* used to load a image from a list, can be modified to work out of core *)
    loadImage[k_] := (
        image = getImage[images[[k]]];
        dims = ImageDimensions[image];
        range = Tuples[{{0}, dims}];
        color = If[ImageMeasurements[image, "MeanIntensity"] < .4, White, Black];
        editQ = False; (* new image might not have associated boxes *)
    );
    (* used to get an updated class list *)
    getClasses[] := Union[Catenate[data[[All, All, 2]]]];
    (* to avoid wrting garbage to the box *)
    safePos[] := If[VectorQ[MousePosition["Graphics"]],
        current = checkCoord@MousePosition["Graphics"],
        current
    ];
    (* code to add a new box,
        it does not trigger if the box is too small to prevent accidentaly adding one
        the box id will be set to the new box
        the class list is updated to pick up new classes *)
    addBox[] := If[
        EuclideanDistance[left, safePos[]] > minMove,
        AppendTo[data[[i]], pointsToRec[left, safePos[]] -> class];
        classes = getClasses[];
        id = Length[data[[i]]];
        first = True
    ];
    (* code to delete a box,
        the box id will be set to the next available one
        the class list is updated to remove unused classes *)
    deleteBox[] := If[Length[data[[i]]] > 0,
        data[[i]] = Delete[data[[i]], id];
        classes = getClasses[];
        id = Min[id, Length[data[[i]]]]
    ];
    (* code to initialize the edited box info *)
    editBox[] := (
        boxcenter = Mean[List @@ data[[i]][[id, 1]]];
        boxsize = Abs[Subtract @@ data[[i]][[id, 1]]];
    );
    checkCoord[new_] := If[clipQ, clipCoords[new, dims], new];
    
    styled[data_] := MapThread[
        {#2, EdgeForm[#2], Button[#1, id = #3; editBox[];, Appearance -> "Frameless"]}&,
        {data[[All, 1]], exprColor /@ data[[All, 2]], Range[Length[data]]}
    ];
    
    (* memoized to reduce overhead, these are small images*)
    thumbnail[pos_] :=  thumbnail[pos] = getImage[images[[pos]], 50];
    carousel[] = Dynamic[With[{window = slidingWindow[thumbID, Length[images], 9]},
        Row[MapIndexed[
            Button[#, (i = thumbID = window[[#2[[1]]]]; loadImage[i]), Appearance -> "Frameless"]&,
            MapAt[Framed, Position[window, i]]@
            MapAt[Framed[#, FrameStyle->Transparent]&, Position[window, Except[i, _Integer]]]@
                ConformImages[thumbnail /@ window, 60, "Fit", Padding -> GrayLevel[.8]]
        ]]
    ], TrackedSymbols :> {id, thumbID}];
    
    (* variable initialization *)
    loadImage[1];
    data = PadRight[Replace[data, Automatic -> {}], Length[images], {{}}];
    classes = Replace[getClasses[], {} -> {"None"}];
    max = Length[images];
    size = {700, 500};
    sizeC = N @ Log[size[[1]]/200];
    class = First[classes];
    
    (* main interface *)
    EventHandler[
    Deploy @
    Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 10, FrameStyle -> LightGray]& @ 
    Grid[{
        (* image carousel *)    
        {Row[{
                Button["\[LeftAngleBracket]\[LeftAngleBracket]", thumbID = Max[1, thumbID - 5 9]], Button["\[LeftAngleBracket]", thumbID = Max[1, thumbID - 9]],
                Column[{carousel[], 
                    Dynamic[Style[StringForm["Showing `` to `` of ``", Sequence@@MinMax[slidingWindow[thumbID, Length[images], 9]], Length[images]], "Text"]]}],
                Button["\[RightAngleBracket]", thumbID = Min[Length[images], thumbID + 9]], Button["\[RightAngleBracket]\[RightAngleBracket]", thumbID = Min[Length[images], thumbID + 5 9]]
            }], SpanFromLeft},
    {
    (* info and controls *)
    Column[{
        (* controls *)
        Grid[{
            {"Clip", Checkbox[Dynamic[clipQ]]},
            {"Guides", Checkbox[Dynamic[guidesQ]]},
            {"Edit", Checkbox[Dynamic[editQ, (editQ = #; editBox[])&], Enabled -> Dynamic[Length[data[[i]]] > 0]]},
            {Slider[Dynamic[sizeC, (sizeC = #; size = 200{1, 5/7}*E^#)&], {0, 3}], SpanFromLeft},
            {Button["Clear", data[[i]] = {}; first = True; draggingQ = False; editQ = False], SpanFromLeft},
            {Button["Save", Print[Iconize[data]]; $LastAnnotation = data], SpanFromLeft},
            {suggestionField[Dynamic[class, (class = #; If[editQ, data[[i]][[id, 2]] = #]; classes = Append[getClasses[], class])&], Dynamic[classes], "label"],
                SpanFromLeft}
        }, Alignment -> Left, BaseStyle -> "Text"],
        (* box list *)
        Pane[
            Dynamic[If[Length[data[[i]]] > 0, Grid[
                MapIndexed[
                    Prepend[#, RadioButton[Dynamic[id, (id = #; editBox[])&], #2[[1]]]]&,
                    MapAt[formatBox, List @@@ data[[i]], {All, 1}]
                ],
                Alignment -> Left], ""]],
            250, ImageSizeAction->"ShrinkToFit", BaseStyle -> {"Text", FontSize -> 14}]
    }],
    (* image panel *)
    Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0, FrameStyle -> LightGray, Background -> GrayLevel[.98]]& @ 
    PaneSelector[{
        True -> Graphics[{
            (* image *)
            Dynamic[Image[image, ImageSize -> size]],
            Dynamic@FaceForm[Opacity[.2, color]], Dynamic@EdgeForm[color],
            (* drawn boxes *)
            Dynamic[styled[data[[i]]]],
            (* controls to edit the current box *)
            Locator[Dynamic[boxcenter, (
                    boxcenter = #;
                    data[[i]][[id, 1, 1]] = checkCoord[boxcenter + boxsize/2];
                    data[[i]][[id, 1, 2]] = checkCoord[boxcenter - boxsize/2];
                )&
            ], locator[Dynamic[color], ImageSize -> 15]],
            Locator[Dynamic[data[[i]][[id, 1, 1]], (data[[i]][[id, 1, 1]] = checkCoord[#]; editBox[])&], locator[Dynamic[color]]],
            Locator[Dynamic[data[[i]][[id, 1, 2]], (data[[i]][[id, 1, 2]] = checkCoord[#]; editBox[])&], locator[Dynamic[color]]]

        },
            ImageSize -> Dynamic[size], PlotRange -> Dynamic[range], ImageMargins -> margin
        ],
        False ->
        EventHandler[
        MouseAppearance[Graphics[{
            (* image *)
            Dynamic[Image[image, ImageSize -> size]],
            Dynamic[color], (*Dynamic@FaceForm[Opacity[.2, color]], Dynamic@EdgeForm[color],*) Opacity[.2],
            (* boxes present in list *)
            {Dynamic[styled[data[[i]]]]},
            Dynamic@If[TrueQ @ first, 
                (* box being currently drawn *)
                {Opacity[Dynamic[If[guidesQ, .5, 0]]], InfiniteLine[mouse, {1,0}], InfiniteLine[mouse, {0,1}]}, 
                (* guide lines *)
                {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Opacity[1]], Rectangle[Dynamic@left, mouse]}
            ],
            (* locator *)
            Inset[locator[Dynamic[color]], mouse, Center, Offset[{25, 25}]]
        },
            ImageSize -> Dynamic[size], PlotRange -> Dynamic[range], ImageMargins -> margin
        ], Graphics[]],
        {
        {"MouseDown", 1} :> If[first,
            (* record first box corner *)
            left = safePos[];
            first = False,
            (* record second box corner and save box *)
            addBox[]
        ],
        {"MouseUp", 1} :> (
            If[!first && draggingQ,
                (* record second box corner and save box *)
                addBox[]
            ];
            draggingQ = False
        ),
        {"MouseClicked", 2} :> If[!first,
            (* cancel current selection *)
            first = True; draggingQ = False,
            (* cancel last selection *)
            deleteBox[]; draggingQ = False
        ],
        "MouseDragged" :> (
            draggingQ = True;
        )
        }
    ]},
        Dynamic[editQ]
    ]
    }}, Alignment->Top],
        {
            "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> (thumbID = i = Max[1, i - 1]; loadImage[i];),
            "RightArrowKeyDown" :> (thumbID = i = Min[max, i + 1]; loadImage[i];),
            "UpArrowKeyDown" :> (j = Min[Length[classes], j + 1]; class = classes[[j]]),
            "DownArrowKeyDown" :> (j = Max[1, j - 1]; class = classes[[j]])
        }
    ]
]
```

---

## Old answer

I used to have an old prototype for this that was in need of a revamp. This gives me the occasion to do it.
The goal is to have an interface which makes the drawing of the boxes as easy as possible an eventually returns something that can be used for training.

This version was built to support the following features:

- interactions

  1. boxes can be drawn by clicking on a corner and then dragging to the other corner
  2. boxes can be drawn by clicking on a corner and then clicking on the other corner
  3. right click while drawing should cancel the current box
  4. right click should cancel the last box drawn
- options

  5. the coordinates can be clipped to the image range
  6. the range can be scaled or the image size
  7. the UI should offer information about the box edges
  8. the UI should be scalable

[image: image annotation animation]

---

With the goals in mind let's start by putting together each element

#### Helpers

- convert coordinates to a region

```
pointsToRec[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}] := Rectangle[{Min[x1, x2], Min[y1, y2]}, {Max[x1, x2], Max[y1, y2]}]
```

- clip coordinates to a max range

```
clipCoords[{x_, y_}, {w_, h_}] := {Clip[x, {0, w}], Clip[y, {0, h}]}
```

- scale coordinates to a new range

```
scaleBox[{w_, h_}][Rectangle[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}]] := Rectangle[{x1 w, y1 h}, {x2 w, y2 h}]
scaleBox[{w_, h_}][list: {__Rectangle}] := scaleBox[{w,h}] /@ list
```

#### Actions

- getting the position

```
"MouseMoved" :> (
            (* store current mouse position *)
            pos = MousePosition["Graphics"];
            If[VectorQ[pos], current = If[clipQ, clipCoords[pos, If[scaledQ, {1, 1}, dims]], pos]];
        )
```

- checking for dragging motion

```
"MouseDragged" :> (
            draggingQ = True;
        )
```

- first clik or press

```
{"MouseDown", 1} :> If[first,
            (* record first box corner *)
            left = current;
            first = False,
        ]
```

- second clik or "unpress" (here the boxes are saved as `Rectangle[] -> class`)

```
{"MouseDown", 1} :> If[!first,
            (* record second box corner and save box *)
            If[
                EuclideanDistance[left, current] > If[scaledQ, .005, 2],
                AppendTo[box, pointsToRec[left, current] -> class];
                first = True
            ]
        ]
```

```
{"MouseUp", 1} :> (
            If[!first && draggingQ,
                (* record second box corner and save box *)
                If[
                    EuclideanDistance[left, current] > If[scaledQ, .005, 2],
                    AppendTo[box, pointsToRec[left, current] -> class];
                    first = True
                ]
            ];
            draggingQ = False
        )
```

- right click while dragging or moving

```
{"MouseClicked", 2} :> If[!first,
            (* cancel current selection *)
            first = True; draggingQ = False,
            (* cancel last selection *)
            If[Length[box] > 0, box = Most[box]]; draggingQ = False
        ],
```

#### Controls

- clip and guides

```
Checkbox[Dynamic[clipQ]]
Checkbox[Dynamic[guidesQ]]
```

- scale

```
Checkbox[Dynamic[scaledQ, 
    (scaledQ = #;
    If[# && Length[box] > 0,
        box[[All,1]] = scaleBox[1/dims][box[[All,1]]], 
        box[[All,1]] = scaleBox[dims][box[[All,1]]]
    ])&
]]
```

- size

```
Slider[Dynamic[sizeC, (sizeC = #; size = 10^#)&], {2, 4}]
```

---

Now we need to put everthing together in a decent UI. My main structure is giong to be

```
Column[{
    controls,
    EventHandler[
        Graphics[],
        actions
    ]
}]
```

And here is the UI in all its gory details

```
ClearAll[boxCreator]
SetAttributes[boxCreator, HoldAll]
boxCreator[Dynamic[box_], Dynamic[class_], Dynamic[i_]] := boxCreator[box, class, i]
boxCreator[box_, class_, i_] := 
DynamicModule[
    {
        (* states *)
        first = True, mouseDown = False, left = {0,0}, current = {0,0}, draggingQ = False, pos = None,
        (* settings*)
        clipQ = True, scaledQ = True, guidesQ = True,
        (* variables *)
        dims, color, margin = 20, size = 400, sizeC, locator
    },
    dims = ImageDimensions[i];
    size = 700;
    sizeC = N @ Log[10, size];
    color = If[ImageMeasurements[i, "MeanIntensity"] < .4, White, Black];
    locator = Graphics@{
                
                {
                    Opacity[Dynamic[.4 Boole[MousePosition["Graphics"] =!= None]]], ColorNegate[color],
                    AbsoluteThickness[3], Circle[{0,0}, 10{1,1}], 
                    Line[{{{-15, 0}, {-5, 0}}, {{5, 0}, {15, 0}}, {{0, -15}, {0, -5}}, {{0, 5}, {0, 15}}}]
                },
                Opacity[Dynamic[Boole[MousePosition["Graphics"] =!= None]]], color,
                Circle[{0,0}, 10{1,1}],
                Line[{{{-15, 0}, {-5, 0}}, {{5, 0}, {15, 0}}, {{0, -15}, {0, -5}}, {{0, 5}, {0, 15}}}]
            };
    Deploy@Column[{
    Row[{
        "Clip", Checkbox[Dynamic[clipQ]],
        "Scale", Checkbox[Dynamic[scaledQ, 
            (scaledQ = #; If[# && Length[box] > 0, box[[All,1]] = scaleBox[1/dims][box[[All,1]]], box[[All,1]] = scaleBox[dims][box[[All,1]]]])&]],
        "Guides", Checkbox[Dynamic[guidesQ]],
        Button["Clear", box = {}; first = True; draggingQ = False]
    }],
    Slider[Dynamic[sizeC, (sizeC = #; size = 10^#)&], {2, 4}],
    Framed[#, FrameMargins->0, FrameStyle->LightGray]& @ 
    EventHandler[
        MouseAppearance[Graphics[{
            (* image *)
            Inset[i, Center, Center, Scaled[1]],
            FaceForm[Opacity[.2, color]], EdgeForm[color],
            (* boxes present in list *)
            {Dynamic[box[[All, 1]]]},
            (* box being currently drawn *)
            {
                Opacity[Dynamic[Boole[!first]]], EdgeForm[Opacity[Dynamic[Boole[!first]]]],
                FaceForm[], Rectangle[Dynamic@left, Dynamic@current]
            },
            (* guide lines *)
            {Opacity[Dynamic[.5 Boole[guidesQ && first && MousePosition["Graphics"] =!= None]], color], InfiniteLine[Dynamic@current, {1,0}], InfiniteLine[Dynamic@current, {0,1}]},
            (* locator *)
            Inset[locator, Dynamic[current], Center, Offset[{25, 25}]]
        },
            ImageSize -> Dynamic[size], PlotRange -> Dynamic@If[scaledQ, {{0,1}, {0,1}}, Tuples[{{0}, dims}]],
            AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio[i],
            ImageMargins -> margin
        ], Graphics[]],
        {
        {"MouseDown", 1} :> If[first,
            (* record first box corner *)
            left = current;
            first = False,
            (* record second box corner and save box *)
            If[
                EuclideanDistance[left, current] > If[scaledQ, .005, 2],
                AppendTo[box, pointsToRec[left, current] -> class];
                first = True
            ]
        ],
        {"MouseUp", 1} :> (
            If[!first && draggingQ,
                (* record second box corner and save box *)
                If[
                    EuclideanDistance[left, current] > If[scaledQ, .005, 2],
                    AppendTo[box, pointsToRec[left, current] -> class];
                    first = True
                ]
            ];
            draggingQ = False
        ),
        {"MouseClicked", 2} :> If[!first,
            (* cancel current selection *)
            first = True; draggingQ = False,
            (* cancel last selection *)
            If[Length[box] > 0, box = Most[box]]; draggingQ = False
        ],
        "MouseMoved" :> (
            (* store current mouse position *)
            pos = MousePosition["Graphics"];
            If[VectorQ[pos], current = If[clipQ, clipCoords[pos, If[scaledQ, {1, 1}, dims]], pos]];
        ),
        "MouseDragged" :> (
            draggingQ = True;
        )
        }
    ]
    }]
]
```

#### Feedback from OP:

This is great work, thank you!

Your function could easily be a system function with a only 3 tweaks:

**Missing essential features:**

1. Needs to work for multiple images (e.g.  out-of-core directory of files) and store the labels per image, which requires navigation controls (right and left arrow keys) to cycle through the images as well as a saving/loading to resume work.
2. Users need to be able to click on a box to edit it after it is drawn, e.g. to move/pan it, resize, or delete it.
3. Users need to be able to change the class (each should have it's own color) with up and down arrow keys.

**Missing nice-to-haves:**

4. Display a scrollable carousel of thumbnails of all the images to visually navigate the directory.
5. Ability to edit "a master list" of classes and toggle them per box or even add new classes.
6. This one is very cool: Accelerate the labeling process by continually retraining the detector (in the background on the labels made thus far) to pre-populate high scoring detections (add a slider for users to set thresholds). Then users can simply accept or edit the proposals on unlabeled images instead of dragging them.

Comment: I can try and expand the code to accommodate suggestions. For once, I would like to have dynamic class selection and box (fine) editing.

Comment: This looks awesome  I'll review tomorrow and send comments

Comment: So here's my feedback in a few badly needed and some nice-to-have features.

Comment: Can we somehow reuse the code for rectangle drawing and editing from Canvas[]? That drawing tools thing gives users the ability to click on already-drawn rectangles to select them and then move, resize, or edit their styles.

Comment: Also it makes sense to have the ability to record which images have been reviewed, so we know the difference between "unlabeled" and "this image has no objs".

Comment: Fantastic! $\,\,$

Comment: @Batracos Do you think you could figure out #2 or #3? I'm stuck on implementing selecting/editing/deleting boxes after they are drawn. Neither can I get the arrow keys to work :(

Comment: @Batracos I added an additional bounty to finish the solution if you're up to it.

Comment: Looks like the OP is asking for Rectangle selection/editing and getting arrow keys working in EventHandler, not so much string completion

Comment: Yeah I read too quickly the comment. I think I am converging to an ugly and hacky solution =) should I edit the answer or add it at the bottom?

Comment: @user5601 I tried to address most of your suggestions, Let me know what you think!

Comment: @Batracos Nice! A few last things: 1) when an image has many labels it's hard to know which one you have to click in the panel to select it, would be easier to click a box directly to select it 2) If you click edit then clear it pinks 3) If you type "f", "faces" doesn't pop up in the menu 4) having different colors per-box or a text overlay would help immensely

Comment: Example of issues in the comment above: 1) confusingness when you want to select a specific rectangle:  https://imgur.com/Pd9IH6l

Comment: 2) Example of the edit+clear bug: https://imgur.com/a/Tb7BvOi

Comment: 3) Example of the text field not autocompleteing and allowing non-class strings: imgur.com/a/HGQtwDr

Comment: 4) the image carousel is not scrollable (this is a problem for 100s or 1000s of images)

Comment: 5) I'm importing all of the images before calling the function - that is not memory scalable: `dir=CreateDirectory["~/Downloads/boxcreatorimgs"];
Do[Export[dir<>"/"<>ToString[i]<>".jpeg",ResourceFunction["RandomPhoto"][500,300]],{i,50}];
fns=FileNames["*.jpeg",dir];
boxCreatorList[Import/@fns]`... how should this really work?

Comment: 6) To help with 1) I'm thinking it should look just like `HighlightImage` with colors+labels or colors+legend: https://imgur.com/a/bXOsrtg

Comment: I see now that my complaint 3) about the text field is not valid... I forgot you are not pre-populating a fixed list of classes that will autocomplete in the new code.

Comment: @Batracos if you can address comment issues 1, 2, 4, and 5, I think it's done and I'll accept/award

Comment: @Batracos I will reward you with the points in the hope that you can address those comment issues (i.e. primarily when are 100+  images or 10+s boxes)

Comment: @user5601 I have modified the code to incorporate your suggestions

Comment: Well this is a beautiful answer! Looks like you added enhanced image loading logic, do we still need to do this to use it: `boxCreatorList[Import /@ fns]`?

Comment: @Batracos Ah I was getting a "failed to load fastimageimport()... error" when I feed it just a list of filenames... but I just fixed it in your second downvalue for getImage.